# Installing request for python on Mac

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to install the requests module on Mac following this tutorial http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/

when I do the command pip install I get the following error:

```
Processing /Users/thomasmakkink/Documents/Acsone/Obfg/requests
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.18.4)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests==2.18.4)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests==2.18.4)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.18.4)
  Using cached certifi-2018.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4.dist-info'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Should you "sudo" it?

Comment: Sorry I just found that by looking around. I'll delete the question

Comment: Is there an equivalent of ‘run as admin’ or ‘sudo’ on Mac? That’s probably what you want to do when installing your package.

Comment: Better, use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pip install requests
```

works well